# Internet connectivity works only after rebooting - Manjaro/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, xfce

I'm now a full time user on Linux. Ubuntu did the job at the beginning but after several months of dealing with unity I thought of switching to KDE. After I got bored of KDE I switched to XFCE and then the problem arrived. If I boot up the PC and log in, internet is not available. eth0 is missing from lspci/ifconfig, only l0 appears. After a reboot, everything is ok. 
After searching and searching, I could not find any clue and thought that Ubuntu may be the fault, so I switched to Manjaro XFCE. Same thing is happening here, but the system is faster and it does not bother me to restart it before I log in.

I don't know if it is a hardware problem or a software bug regarding the network manager in Manjaro, but if I boot from a Live USB, everything is ok.

How can I solve this problem, so that my internet would work without rebooting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect three possibilities:

- hardware failure (broken components or just unrealiable conections)
- driver failure (dosn't handle some state correctly)
- software failure (dosn't bring up interface because of some feature/bug)

Things to try (You may need to adjust/change commands used):

```
ifconfig -a
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

You can also try reloading driver module using `rmmod` / `modprobe`.

*EDIT:*

Since previous attempts didn't help, I would suspect something hardware related (unreliable connection, fried component, etc). If reboot helps, problem may be related to power - You may try:

- instead of reboot turn off PC completely (maybe even unplug from utility power), wait a few minutes and turn on it again;
- try resetting machine before OS starts booting (turn on, wait until bootloader is displayed and reset);
- try take-out and insert LAN card (if it is not integrated).

*EDIT2:*

From comments it is clear the problem is related to *"TCS fast calibration failed"* message during boot. A few things to try:

- check `cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource` - are contents different when internet is working and when it is not?
- try adding kernel boot parameter `clocksource=acpi_pm` or `clocksource=hpet` (got idea fro [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1210044#p1210044) page)
- check PSU for [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) (MB already checked as per comments)
- try removing LAN card - do You still see TSC error?
- if it is an option - try installing some older Linux distribution **to hard disk** (not CD/USB boot) and see if it works better with LAN card.
- try replacing PSU or LAN card, as these are components which most likely may be out-of-order.

From my experience, I would bet the source is PSU (had seen enough weird problems on similar hardware).

*EDIT4:*

Seems it is not PSU... If other options above fail, try capturing:

```
dmesg > boot.log
```

And check for differencies when LAN is working, and when it is not. You should see at least TSC error which You decsribed before, but there may be other differencies too:

```
diff bott_ok.log boot_fail.log
```

*EDIT5:*

From the comments it seams problem is related to PCI enumaration during cold-reset and hot-reset, identified using `lspci` while in GRUB loader (before Linux kernel loads). Things to try:

- boot kernel using options like `reset_devices`, `nobios`, `conf1`, `conf2` (just a few which got my attention, You can find many more in `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`, look for BIOS or PCI related options first);
- sice machine loads successfully from USB, pluging in USB device while booting from HDD may trigger correct behaviour.

*EDIT6:*

Clear BIOS settings (reset, clear using jumper on MB, upgrade/rewrite). Try playing with "Reset configuration data", "PnP OS installed", PCI timings or similar BIOS sertings.

Comment: Tried those commands but nothing worked. My NIC is not even listed, but after reboot I got this in lspci: Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 11)
.

Comment: Did some research and found out that the corresponding kernel module is tg3, but nothing happened when I restarted it.

Comment: @crishu, is this interface visible at all (after `ifconfig -a`)? Can You bring it up if visible (or some error is displayed)?

Comment: interface is not visible. can't even find the device.

Comment: @crishu, I've updated the answer. It may help if You describe Your hardware more precisely (desktop/laptop, age, CPU & MB, LAN card, PSU). Also You may inspect MB and PSU for "capacitor plague" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).

Comment: here: http://imgur.com/a/Tdwaw Checked MB, everything is ok.

Comment: also I noticed something strange. when internet is working, I see an error occurring at boot: "TSC fast calibration failed". When internet is working, this error does not occur. I believe that has something to do with the kernel booting or with grub.

Comment: And what about capacitors inside ower supply? If PSU is similar age as specs You have shown it is quite likely to be the source of this problem. Good point You noticed TSC failure (I gues it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter). I'll update an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: PSU is from another PC. Changed the PSU now and still the same. As for the LAN card, it is integrated.

Comment: Updated answer. I'm still not sure if it is hardware,, or software problem.

Comment: Here are the differences:  http://pastebin.com/nvhniicL first log is without internet, second with.

Comment: Try removing timestamps before runing difff, or just paste original files.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zaT8uD6i - cold boot - no internet

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Rx0dGbUt - after restart - internet working

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L9cLifth - diff without timestamps

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but may be some delay required for this device to initialize properly, or CMOS battery is weak (got these ideas from here http://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/52758-new-pcie-card-not-recognized-cold-boot-works-perfect-restarts-why.html - seems to be a very similar problem, but on Windows machine). You may try to delay booting (just bay going into bootloader or BIOS for a minute). From `dmesg` listings I suspect this device is not detected quite early in boot process (look for `pci 0000:07:00.0` in dmesg output).

Comment: will try tomorrow. happy new year btw !

Comment: so, hanging in bootloader did nothing, but in BIOS it worked, maybe because it restarted itself on exit.

Comment: How does it work if You warm-reboot (Ctrl-Alt-Del) and cold-reboot (reset button) from bootloader? Happy New Year :)

Comment: both ways work from the bootloader.

Comment: Got an idea. I'll verify if the NIC is loaded in grub on cold boot with lspci.

Comment: On cold boot, ethernet card is not available, but after a reboot, it is. So after all, it is a hardware problem...

Comment: Just to clarify: did You booted linux kernel, or checked `lspci` from grub? If card is not visible from grub, it would mean BIOS is not doing PCI enumeration correctly on cold-boot. Kernel has number of parameters, which may be usefull, for example `reset_devices`, `nobios`, `conf1`, `conf2` (just a few which got my attention, You can find many more in `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` in Your kernel's source).

Comment: I did lspci in grub, so kernel was not booted.

Comment: It'd be great if you could not use comments as a replacement for [chat]. Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely a hardware problem. I'll have to replace the MB. Thank you for your help, kestasx!

Comment: @slhck, I think crishu has <20 rep, so he'll be unable to participate in chat room, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @crishu, You wrote You can boot from USB successfully (and this dosn't fit into the whole picture for me), so I wouldn't be so sure You need to replace hardware (unless You've found something). Maybe pluging in USB (but booting from HDD) would help?

Comment: @kestasx True, I missed that. You're right. I believe there is a way to invite people to chat even if they have less than 20 rep, but only moderators can do that and I forgot how.

Comment: @kestasx Tried it now from USB and it doesn't work. It used to work perfectly, but idk what happened. Changed HDD, used less RAM to preserve power, unplugged some of the fans, but nothing.

Comment: @crishu, there may be options in BIOS like _"Reset configuration data"_, _"PnP OS installed"_ and PCI/PCIe related timings and settings. Also BIOS update, or just rewrite, cleaning CMOS via jumper may fix the problem.

Comment: It works!!! I restored the BIOS default values, and when I booted up it said: "error: Expansion ROM not initialized for PCI Network Controller on MB". I remember the last time I got this error I modified the BIOS location, from Expansion ROM to TOP OF BASE MEMORY. Now I left it to Expansion ROM and disabled LAN REMOTE BOOT, and everything works! Thank you mate! Saved me a couple of bucks.